# Python: Memory leak debugging

Tags: python, django, debugging, memory-leaks

I have a small multithreaded script running in django and over time its starts using more and more memory. Leaving it for a full day eats about 6GB of RAM and I start to swap.

Following http://www.lshift.net/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks I see this as the most common types (with only 800M of memory used):

```
(Pdb)  objgraph.show_most_common_types(limit=20)
dict                       43065
tuple                      28274
function                   7335
list                       6157
NavigableString            3479
instance                   2454
cell                       1256
weakref                    974
wrapper_descriptor         836
builtin_function_or_method 766
type                       742
getset_descriptor          562
module                     423
method_descriptor          373
classobj                   256
instancemethod             255
member_descriptor          218
property                   185
Comment                    183
__proxy__                  155
```

which doesn't show anything weird. What should I do now to help debug the memory problems?

*Update:* Trying some things people are recommending. I ran the program overnight, and when I work up, 50% * 8G == 4G of RAM used.

```
(Pdb) from pympler import muppy
(Pdb) muppy.print_summary()
                                     types |   # objects |   total size
========================================== | =========== | ============
                                   unicode |      210997 |     97.64 MB
                                      list |        1547 |     88.29 MB
                                      dict |       41630 |     13.21 MB
                                       set |          50 |      8.02 MB
                                       str |      109360 |      7.11 MB
                                     tuple |       27898 |      2.29 MB
                                      code |        6907 |      1.16 MB
                                      type |         760 |    653.12 KB
                                   weakref |        1014 |     87.14 KB
                                       int |        3552 |     83.25 KB
                    function (__wrapper__) |         702 |     82.27 KB
                        wrapper_descriptor |         998 |     77.97 KB
                                      cell |        1357 |     74.21 KB
  <class 'pympler.asizeof.asizeof._Claskey |        1113 |     69.56 KB
                       function (__init__) |         574 |     67.27 KB
```

That doesn't sum to 4G, nor really give me any big data structured to go fix. The unicode is from a set() of "done" nodes, and the list's look like just random `weakref`s.

I didn't use guppy since it required a C extension and I didn't have root so it was going to be a pain to build.

None of the objectI was using have a `__del__` method, and looking through the libraries, it doesn't look like django nor the python-mysqldb do either. Any other ideas?

Comment: "running in Django"?  Do you mean that you're using the Django web server for doing additional non-web-service background processing?  Have you considered splitting this non-web-serving stuff into a separate process?

Comment: It is a cron job that imports the Django settgings.py and uses many of the Django ORM features. So, it isn't spawned by a webserver, but still uses many of the features (which might have been pertinent)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See http://opensourcehacker.com/2008/03/07/debugging-django-memory-leak-with-trackrefs-and-guppy/ . Short answer: if you're running django but not in a web-request-based format, you need to manually run `db.reset_queries()` (and of course have DEBUG=False, as others have mentioned). Django automatically does `reset_queries()` after a web request, but in your format, that never happens.

Comment: db.reset_queries() solved a problem for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 21):

Is DEBUG=False in settings.py?

If not Django will happily store all the SQL queries you make which adds up.

Comment: wow, I knew writing the words django in there would help. Yes, my script wasn't using my production settings.py. *embarrassed*. Lets see if it clears up the memory problem.

Comment: This is it! The DEBUG set to True really eats up lots of memory when selecting from large database.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [gc.set_debug()](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.set_debug) ?

You need to ask yourself simple questions:

- Am I using objects with `__del__` methods? Do I absolutely, unequivocally, need them?
- Can I get reference cycles in my code? Can't we break these circles before getting rid of the objects?

See, the main issue would be a cycle of objects containing `__del__` methods:

```
import gc

class A(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print 'a deleted'
        if hasattr(self, 'b'):
            delattr(self, 'b')

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __del__(self):
        print 'b deleted'
        del self.a


def createcycle():
    a = A()
    b = B(a)
    a.b = b
    return a, b

gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)

a, b = createcycle()

# remove references
del a, b

# prints:
## gc: uncollectable <A 0x...>
## gc: uncollectable <B 0x...>
## gc: uncollectable <dict 0x...>
## gc: uncollectable <dict 0x...>
gc.collect()

# to solve this we break explicitely the cycles:
a, b = createcycle()
del a.b

del a, b

# objects are removed correctly:
## a deleted
## b deleted
gc.collect()
```

I would really encourage you to flag objects / concepts that are cycling in your application and focus on their lifetime: when you don't need them anymore, do we have anything referencing it?

Even for cycles without `__del__` methods, we can have an issue:

```
import gc

# class without destructor
class A(object): pass

def createcycle():
    # a -> b -> c 
    # ^         |
    # ^<--<--<--|
    a = A()
    b = A()
    a.next = b
    c = A()
    b.next = c
    c.next = a
    return a, b, b

gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)

a, b, c = createcycle()
# since we have no __del__ methods, gc is able to collect the cycle:

del a, b, c
# no panic message, everything is collectable:
##gc: collectable <A 0x...>
##gc: collectable <A 0x...>
##gc: collectable <dict 0x...>
##gc: collectable <A 0x...>
##gc: collectable <dict 0x...>
##gc: collectable <dict 0x...>
gc.collect()

a, b, c = createcycle()

# but as long as we keep an exterior ref to the cycle...:
seen = dict()
seen[a] = True

# delete the cycle
del a, b, c
# nothing is collected
gc.collect()
```

If you have to use "seen"-like dictionaries, or history, be careful that you keep only the actual data you need, and no external references to it.

I'm a bit disappointed now by `set_debug`, I wish it could be configured to output data somewhere else than to stderr, but hopefully [that should change soon](http://bugs.python.org/issue5851).

Comment: gc.collect() is returning everything as collectible, and on the second invocation returns 0. That means I don't have any cycles right?

Comment: @Paul: No, you can still have cycles. Look at the very last example I gave: here, gc.collect() does return 0, and nothing is printed. If you have cycles of objects that don't have __del__ methods, gc will stay quiet.

Answer (score 6):

See [this excellent blog post from Ned Batchelder](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200809/a_server_memory_leak.html) on how they traced down real memory leak in HP's Tabblo. A classic and worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use different tools. Apparently, the statistics you got is only about GC objects (i.e. objects which may participate in cycles); most notably, it lacks strings.

I recommend to use [Pympler](http://code.google.com/p/pympler/); this should provide you with more detailed statistics.

Comment: top shows my app using 7% * 8GB = 560M. pympler.muppy.print_summary() shows around 55M. Where is the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use any extension? They are a wonderful place for memory leaks, and will not be tracked by python tools.

Comment: No extensions, but a good place for others stumbling here to look.

Comment: If you use Django ORM, you use extension module - DB-API database driver. Is this MySQLdb? Current version has known cursor memory leak when connection is established with use_unicode=True (which is the case for Django>=1.0).

Comment: yes, you are right on the money! I'm using all of those. Any known solution?

Comment: Try with the code from SVN, the leak has been fixed but update has not been released yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Guppy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/).

Basicly, you need more information or be able to extract some. Guppy even provides graphical representation of data.