# Python: how to "kill" a class instance/object?

Tags: python, class, oop

I want a Roach class to "die" when it reaches a certain amount of "hunger", but I don't know how to delete the instance. I may be making a mistake with my terminology, but what I mean to say is that I have a ton of "roaches" on the window and I want specific ones to disappear entirely.

I would show you the code, but it's quite long. I have the Roach class being appended into a Mastermind classes roach population list.

Comment: `del <instance>` ?

Answer (score 25):

In general:

- Each binding variable -> object increases internal object's reference counter
- there are several usual ways to decrease reference (dereference object -> variable binding):

  1. exiting block of code where variable was declared (used for the first time)
  2. destructing object will release references of all attributes/method variable -> object references
  3. calling `del variable` will also delete reference in the current context
- after all references to one object are removed (counter==0) it becomes good candidate for garbage collection, but it is not guaranteed that it will be processed ([reference here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)):

> CPython currently uses a reference-counting scheme with (optional)
>   delayed detection of cyclically linked garbage, which collects most
>   objects as soon as they become unreachable, but is not guaranteed to
>   collect garbage containing circular references. See the documentation
>   of the gc module for information on controlling the collection of
>   cyclic garbage. Other implementations act differently and CPython may
>   change. Do not depend on immediate finalization of objects when they
>   become unreachable (ex: always close files).

- how many references on the object exists, use [sys.getrefcount](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount)
- module for configure/check garbage collection is [gc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#module-gc)
- GC will call [object.__ del__](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) method when destroying object ([additional reference here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html))
- some immutable objects like strings are handled in a special way - e.g. if two vars contain same string, it is possible that they reference the same object, but some not - check [identifying objects, why does the returned value from id(...) change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402679/identifying-objects-why-does-the-returned-value-from-id-change#3402717)
- id of object can be found out with builtin function [id](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)
- module [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) looks interesting - *A module for monitoring memory usage of a python program*
- there is lot of useful resources for the topic, one example: [Find all references to an object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891755/find-all-references-to-an-object-in-python/11891904#11891904)

Answer (score 13):

You cannot force a Python object to be deleted; it will be deleted when nothing references it (or when it's in a cycle only referred to be the items in the cycle). You will have to tell your "Mastermind" to erase its reference.

```
del somemastermind.roaches[n]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,roach in enumerate(roachpopulation_list)
        if roach.hunger == 100
            del roachpopulation_list[i]
            break
```

Remove the instance by deleting it from your population list (containing all the roach instances.

If your Roaches are Sprites created in Pygame, then a simple command of .kill would remove the instance.

Comment: can you also not do the numeration, and just `roachpopulation_list.remove(roach)`, then `del roach`? It seems to me both approaches should be equivalent, but I'm not sure

Comment: You could use any of the functions in Python to remove the instance from the list, like delete, remove, pop etc. Once an instance is no longer stored in a list or dictionary or variable etc, it's forgotten.