# Class Instance deletion in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to have a class delete an instance of itself. I know for variables you can do `del x` but how do you do that for classes? If I do something like:

```
class foo(object):
    x=5
    def __init__(self):
        print "hi"
    def __del__(self):
        del self
        print "bye"

a = foo()
a.__del__()
print a.x
```

The output of the code is

```
hi
bye
5
```

The instance of foo wasn't deleted. Is there a way to make a class do this?

Comment: `del a` maybe? It did the trick here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686788/python-how-to-kill-a-class-instance-object

Comment: For the record, `x` isn't even an attribute of `a`, it's a class attribute of `foo`; it's not going to go away whether or not the `foo` instance referenced by `a` exists or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you have a reference to an instance of the class, then by definition it has remaining references. You can use the `del` keyword to delete a name (releasing the reference from that name to the object), but if a reference to the instance is held elsewhere, the instance remains.

If what you're going for is deterministic cleanup behavior, don't use `__del__` (which is not deterministic in an obvious or consistent way, and prior to Python 3.4, could cause reference cycle leaks if any member of the cycle was an instance of a class that defined a `__del__` finalizer). Have the class implement [the context manager protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager), and use instances with `with` statements to get deterministic cleanup; the instance will still exist until the last reference goes away, but as long as `__exit__` performs the necessary release of resources, the empty shell of the instance costs you almost nothing.

As an example of context management, we'll make `x` an instance attribute of `foo`, not a class attribute, and we'll say we need ensure the instance's reference to `x` goes away at a known time (note, because `del` just deletes our reference, if someone else saved off `a.x`, the object won't actually be freed until the other reference(s) are also released):

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print "hi"
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print "bye"
        del self.x

with foo(123456789) as a:
    print a.x  # This works, because a.x still exists
# bye is printed at this point
print a.x # This fails, because we deleted the x attribute in __exit__ and the with is done
# a still exists until it goes out of scope, but it's logically "dead" and empty
```

Answer (score 0):

By defining `__del__` I believe you're overriding the default behavior of `del`. As you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__), `__del__` is called once the reference count of an object reaches 0. It is not recommended to use `__del__` unless you know what you're doing.

EDIT: this is incorrect, please check shadowranger's answer. Although the link is still relevant to python 2

Comment: This is flat wrong. `del` the keyword deletes a name (or in some cases, references from within a container) and thereby releases references to the object associated with that name. But if there are other references elsewhere, `del` does nothing but (in CPython) decrement the reference count. `__del__` is invoked when the last reference goes away, regardless of whether `del` was involved or not. The two are only tangentially related; `del` itself does nothing differently for instances of classes with or without `__del__`, only the Python garbage disposal process changes.

Comment: Well there you go, I obviously haven't done my homework on CPython garbage collection. Looks like I learned something today too, however I believe you jumped the gun a bit. I never said `__del__` was invoked specifically by `del` and reference count equaling zero is the same as no references however I'll absolutely 100% concede my answer was misleading and the first sentence was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

`del a` should do the trick:

Code:

```
class foo(object):
    x=5
    def __init__(self):
        print "hi"
    def __del__(self):
        del self
        print "bye"

a = foo()
del a
print a.x
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py
hi
here
bye
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print a.x
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```