# Python:How do I delete every instance of a class in a list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to delete every instance of a class in a `for` loop. However, there is a point in which the list length meets the `for` loop iteration. See:

> ```
>     for n in range(len(myList)):
>         print(len(myList), n)
>         del myList[n]
> ```

Output:

```
15 0
14 1
13 2
12 3
11 4
10 5
9 6
8 7
7 8
IndexError: list assignment index out of range`
```

The only solution that came across my head so far was to create a variable for each item in the list and deleting them that way, but I've heard that's usually not something you need to do. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: `while myList: myList.pop(0)`? But it's not really clear what you are doing this rather than just assigning an empty list to `myList`.

Comment: You're looking for `for n in reversed(range(len(myList))):`, but that's not very pythonic. Instead, you should probably use `for n, item in enumerate(myList):` (or, if you don't need the index, just use `for item in myList:`)

Comment: @Mark Meyer This list contains references to instances of classes. If I wanted to assign an empty list to `myList`, then I think I'd use ```.clear()```

Comment: What does references to classes have to do with anything?

Comment: I'm trying to delete them, and I can't do that just by clearing them off the list because they have references to each other.

Comment: `del` doesn't delete objects. There is no way to delete objects manually in Python.

Comment: Don't worry about circular references. The garbage collector will handle those.

Comment: @user2357 Thank you for clarifying. However, I seem to reach the recursion limit before it gets collected... [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16687693/11228943) states that the garbage collector is not guaranteed to collect circular references. Could this be the case?

Comment: If you're hitting the recursion limit, that has nothing to do with memory reclamation.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I meant that I hit the recursion limit because the garbage collector didn't seem get rid of the class instances which call each other's functions, leading to the limit

Comment: This description is ambiguous and doesn't give us enough to go on. If you're having an infinite recursion bug, post a question about the bug, with a [mcve] so we can actually debug it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to step through the list backwards.

```
for n in range (len (myList) -1, -1, -1):
```