# python - Finding a leaking object

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, guppy

I have a large python code base.

At one point I find out (using `guppy` but that doesn't really matter) that I have an existing instance of my class `BigClass`.

At this point of the code I do not expect to have any living instances of `BigClass` since all of them were supposed to be released. I tried calling `gc.collect()`

How can I trace down where is this instance, why is it still alive, its properties and so on?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33398553/3280538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all instances of the class:

```
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if isinstance(obj, BigClass):
        # DEBUG IT
```

For debugging the actual objects and how are they referenced:

```
for ref in gc.get_referrers(obj):
    # Should probably filter here to reduce the amount of data printed and avoid printing locals() as well
    print(ref)
```