# Django memory leak: possible causes?

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks, uwsgi

I've a Django application that every so often is getting into memory leak.

I am not using large data that could overload the memory, in fact the application 'eats' memory incrementally (in a week the memory goes from ~ 70 MB to 4GB), that is why I suspect the garbage collector is missing something, I am not sure though. Also, it seems as this increment is not dependant of the number of requests.

Obvious things like `DEBUG=True`, leaving open files, etc... no apply here.

I'm using `uWSGI 2.0.3` (+ nginx) and `Django 1.4.5`

I could set up `wsgi` so that restart the server when the memory exceeds certain limit, but I wouldn't like to do that since that is not a solution really.

Are there any well know situations where the garbage collector "doesn't do its work properly"? Could it provide some code examples?

Is there any configuration of uWSGI + Django that could cause this?

Comment: What's the evidence that there is a memory leak? And, we'll need to see some actual code.

Comment: isn't it enough evidence the increcement from 400 MB to 4G ? What part of the code you need?

Comment: Re: "What part of the code you need?" Pretend someone was asking you this question. What would help you answer? I am thinking that code and configuration would be a good start. Anything else and people are just guessing on your behalf.

Comment: Got it @hughdbrown, but I couldn't to put the entire project code here and also this isn't the idea, as you can see my questions are flexibles: "Are there any well know situations...", "Is there any configuration of uWSGI + Django that could cause..."  in order to get some well know situations/issues around memory leak in Django.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I haven't found the exact stuff I'm looking for (each project is a world!), but following some clues and advices I managed to solve the issue. I share with you a few links that could help if you are facing a similar problem.

[django memory leaks, part I](http://blog.gingerlime.com/2011/django-memory-leaks-part-i/), [django memory leaks, part II](http://blog.gingerlime.com/2011/django-memory-leaks-part-ii/) and [Finding and fixing memory leaks in Python](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1555/optimized-script-for-nginx-and-uwsgi-on-ubuntu-1204)

Some useful SO answers/questions:
[Which Python memory profiler is recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/which-python-memory-profiler-is-recommended), [Is there any working memory profiler for Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758699/is-there-any-working-memory-profiler-for-python3), [Python memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435415/python-memory-leaks) and [Python: Memory leak debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339293/python-memory-leak-debugging)

**Update**

[pyuwsgimemhog](https://github.com/xrmx/pyuwsgimemhog) is a new tool that helps to find out where the leak is.

Answer (score 3):

Django doesn't have known memory leak issues.

I had a similar memory issue. I found that there is a slow SQL causing a high DB CPU percentage. The memory issue is fixed after I fixed the slow SQL.